# VS Code: Remote Container: Using SSH

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote

I have a python app that needs access to private repository which is mentioned in the Dockerfile like this:
`RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install -r requirements.txt`
I have followed instruction from [this official docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/build_enhancements/#using-ssh-to-access-private-data-in-builds) and things are working fine when I do
`docker build --ssh default=C:\Users\Ravi.Kumar\.ssh\id_rsa -t somename:latest .`   from the command line in host machine.
Now I am trying to get this to work using the VSCode `Remote Container` extension. I am getting this in the logs when opening the project in a container using the `Remote Contaienr` extension:

```
Container server: Remote to local stream terminated with error: {
  message: 'connect ENOENT \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent',
  name: 'Error',
  stack: 'Error: connect ENOENT \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent\n' +
    '\tat PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16)'
}
```

Also then the remote container starts, I can see this is the docker build command being used:
`Start: Run: docker build -f d:\Code\somename\Dockerfile -t vsc-somename-8afa92e4f821805c825a5facd311c4f9 d:\Code\somename`

devcontainer.json file:

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the README at:
// https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/tree/v0.217.4/containers/docker-existing-dockerfile
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
    "context": "..",
    "dockerFile": "../Dockerfile",
    "settings": {},
    "build": {},
    "extensions": []
}
```

Question: How do I tell `Remote Container` extension to use the `--ssh` arg in the `docker build` command.

Comment: I found a [related issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/106#issuecomment-558494074). It seems to be built in out of the box in devcontainer. Did you enable your ssh-agent locally?

Comment: Also, the [related docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_using-ssh-keys) is here.

Comment: @ikhvjs This might be helpful, I will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this reference page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/devcontainerjson-reference) can help you find the right syntax to customize docker commands using the `devcontainer.json`.

Unfortunately, it seems you can't specify arguments to be passed to your `docker build` command directly.
You can only pass in `build-args`:

```json
"build": { "args": { "MYARG": "MYVALUE"} }
```

A potential workaround to your problem can be to build the image using the command line you mentionned, and then running `Attach to running container...` vscode action to work inside it from your vscode instance.

Comment: This will add a build time custom argument (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg), which is different

Comment: Oops, you're right. Another solution I can see to work around this limitation is to build your container using the command line you mentioned, and then use the "Attach to running container..." option in vscode. It's not ideal, but better than no solution.